# can't insert data into database in wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I created a form in wordpress but this code isn't work .

```
<?php

$metaname = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['apply_name']);
$metakey = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['apply_email']);
$metavalue = $wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['regcat']);

$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
                "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->jz_users
        ( user_login, user_email, category )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", array(
            $metaname,
            $metakey,
            $metavalue
                )
        ));
?>
```

Comment: use `$wpdb->show_errors();` to check the error into your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
            "
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->jz_users
    ( user_login, user_email, category )
    VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
", array(
        $metaname,
        $metakey,
        $metavalue
            )
    ));
```

might be the table name should be like `$wpdb->users` instead of `$wpdb->jz_users`:

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->users 
        ( user_login, user_email, category )
    VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )", 
    array(
        $metaname,
        $metakey,
        $metavalue
            )
    ));
$wpdb->show_errors();
```

because the `wpdb` class takes care of the prefix used in database and you are using the table name with prefix.

Comment: Thanks, Database connects now. But it goes blank records.. how to solve this plz? :)

Comment: @user2428537 make sure that you are getting the value of `$metaname, $metakey, $metavalue`?

Comment: It does not take form values..my code is below
<form id="apply" method="post">
               <input type="text" name="apply_name" />
   <input type="text" name="apply_email" />
   <select name="regcat">
                                             <option value="Account">Graphics</option>
                                              <option value="Markerting">IT</option>
                                                
                                          </select>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">sind</button>
        </form>

Comment: @user2428537 hope you are making a plugin? make me correct if i am wrong.

Comment: no,i want to create a contact form so i created this form but i can't get the values of the fields of this form..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$wpdb->insert( 
    $wpdb->prefix . 'users', 
        array( 
            'spam'            => 0, 
            'user_status'     => 0, 
            'deleted'         => 0, 
            'old_user_id'     =>125,
            'user_login'      =>'test', 
            'user_pass'       =>md5('admin')

        )
); 
?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.